# Theorem which predicts chaos

Tags: noethers-theorem, chaos-theory

Is there some Theorem which predicts chaos in physics?

As a vage analogy there is the Noether Theorem, which predicts for a system with a certain symmetry some conservation law (and let's us compute this law).

In a similar fashion I am asking for a theorem which would predict that the physical system will be chaotic (and also would predict in which sense it will be chaotic).

Comment: Why would such a theorem be associated with Noether?

Comment: A system can be chaotic and still conserve energy and momentum.

Comment: What about Kolmogorov-Arnold-Moser?  It doesn't quite "predict chaos" but does give some criteria for stability under perturbation...

Comment: Javier, so what? The physical system could satisfy the "chaos theorem" and the Noether theorem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noether proved that if any differentiable symmetry (a feature of a system that changes through time via a smooth continuous function) preserves itself as an unchanged quantity during a transformation of the system, then there must be an associated conservation law that governs the symmetry during the system's transformations. This is called [Noether's Theorem](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/noether.html).

Noether's Theorem applies to any system, whether the system persists robustly during changes, or whether it devolves swiftly into apparent chaos from any slight change to its initial conditions, as Javier noted in his comment.

[Chaos theory](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3202497/) deals with how sensitive a system may be to its initial conditions, and how even minor and seemingly insignificant events can cause complex systems to deviate wildly from initial conditions, leading to what may appear to be [chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory).  It may become extremely difficult to predict how a complex system will evolve through time, and there may be doubt about whether it's even possible.

It's uncertain whether the nature of the Universe permits there to be a theory of chaos with the same provable validity as Noether's Theorem.  For example, a study of dynamic systems may be affected by whether time and space are continuous or granular.  To my knowledge, this has not been resolved.

As ZeroTheHero noted in his comment, the KAM (Kolmogorov, Arnold, Moser) Theorem shows that a quasi periodic motion in an integrable system may persist through minor perturbations of the system.  But more substantial perturbations can throw the system into unpredictable chaos.  This might be taken as a prediction of chaos under certain conditions.

The KAM Theorem, though, is known mainly for its usefulness in predicting stability, rather than chaos, through changes.

[Quantum fluctuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) in the initial condition of the Universe may have had a profound effect upon the present structure of the Universe.  If this could be proved, it might be evidence that chaos is fundamental to the Universe.

Answer (score 0):

Deterministic chaotic behavior is typically classified by some measures applied to  the phase-space of the underlying nonlinear dynamical system. For instance, the Ljapunow exponents $\lambda_i$, the Hausdorff-dimension $D_1$, the Correlation-dimension $C_2$, the Kaplan-Yorke-Dimension $D_{KY}$ or the Kolmogorov-Sinai entropy $K_1$ are the most prominent of them. These are definitions but not theorems. Only the properties of these measures are fixed in theorems about them.